# how to extend the list in python without empty items

Tags: python, django, list

I am extending the list with querysets like this:

```
a_objs = MyModelOne.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
b_objs = MyModelTwo.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)


l = []
l.extend( (list(a_objs), list(b_objs)) )
```

but since `a_objs` is empty, i am getting a list of lists: `[ [], [<MyModelOne: blabla>] ]`

how can i avoid those empty lists in some cool way? :)

Comment: First off, you override the list type with an empty list.

Comment: What he's trying to say is that you should not use 'list' as a name because it is the inbuilt type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list.extend(y for y in (list(x) for x in (a_objs, b_objs)) if y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a list of lists? Why not just extend your destination lists with the results from your source lists, which will have no side effects if you try and add an empty list.

```
a_objs = []
b_objs = ['hello', 'world']

l = []
l.extend(a_objs)
l.extend(b_objs)

print l
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter out falsies (such as an empty list), `no_falsies = filter(None, to_filter)`

```
l = filter(None, l)
```

Comment: It would be better to avoid adding 'falsies' into the list in the first place rather than adding them and removing them later.

Comment: Agreed. Still a valid option though. I find it extremely clear / has human readable value.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita yep, this is very nice and clear. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

`list.extend` only accepts one argument, which you provide as a 2-tuple.  That itself got cast into a list so that's your problem.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend((list(''), list('def')))
>>> l
[[], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Now if you want to join multiple lists together, you could use `itertools.chain` which will do this for you.

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(list(''), list('def')))
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Using `l` as a variable name is also generally considered bad practice due to it being easily to confuse with `I` or `1` (which I violated here), but way better than overriding builtin types.

Comment: Best to make names as explicit as possible.

Comment: @metatoaster, yeah, i just did this in this post to make it clear. in my real code it is ``res_list``. :)